# Indexing in Windows 10 is totally random - problems with Groove Music

Tags: search-indexing, groove-music

I asked this already on some other sites, but no answers were really given or useful. So, I might try here as well.

Groove Music - the default music app in windows 10 is behaving a bit weird lately.

It's about Groove Music, but i think it's an indexing issue. The symptoms are as follows: when I add a series of mp3s in my folder, which is set as default music location in Groove Music, the files aren't being added. This app did behave in a manner that you had to wait a few seconds, perhaps a minute, to add the new files - the refresh of the library wasn't instant. But now it just doesn't refresh the library anymore. Or it does, after a few hours (somewhere around 8 hours or more).

So I investigated a bit and found out that I have to manually rebuild indexes (using this option: http://www.winbeta.org/sites/default...?itok=AXFIURoi), in order to get the new music into groove music. This seems absurd, since it never happened before.

The folder where I copy mp3s is being watched. If I do rebuild indexes, I immediately see the added folders in Groove Music, otherwise I don't - at all.

Plus, if I add for example, "myfile.txt" into the folder where mp3s are suppose to be, cortana finds that immediately. However, I have currently an album in Groove Music, which Cortana doesn't find.

I really have no idea what's going on anymore. Please, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had serious problems with indexing. Had to solve it by deleting a value in registry and then Windows rebuild indexes from scratch and everything worked well. The problem was in the indexing and not groove music